# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm building a React Native app, currently trying to implement an authentication registration system through Firebase. here is my whole code.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView, View, YellowBox, LogBox, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat, InputToolbar } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import AnimatedLoader from "react-native-animated-loader";
import firebaseSDK from "../../firebaseSDK";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);
const customtInputToolbar = props => {
    return (
        <InputToolbar
            {...props}
            containerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderTopColor: "#E8E8E8",
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                //padding: 8
            }}
        />
    );
};
export default class Chat extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            messages: [],
            chatgenidres: '',
        }
        
        this.init()
        this.checkAuth()
    }
    init = () => {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
             firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs",
                authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

            })
        }
    };

    checkAuth = () => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (!user) {
                firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
            }
        })
    }
    send = messages => {
        console.log(messages);
        messages.forEach(item => {
            const message = {
                text: item.text,
                timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                user: item.user
            };
            this.db.push(message);
        });

    };

    parse = message => {
        const { user, text, timestamp } = message.val();
        const { key: _id } = message;
        const createdAt = new Date(timestamp);

        return {
            _id,
            createdAt,
            text,
            user
        };
    };

    get = callback => {
        this.db.on("child_added", snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
    };

    off() {
        this.db.off();
    }

    get db() {
        console.log(this.state.chatgenidres)
        return firebase.database().ref(this.state.chatgenidres)
    };
    get uid() {
        return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
    }
    get user() {
        return {
            _id: this.uid,
            chatfromusername: this.props.navigation.state.params.chatFromName,
            chatfromuserid: this.props.navigation.state.params.chatFromId,
            chattouserid: this.props.navigation.state.params.chatToId,
            chattousername: this.props.navigation.state.params.chatToName,
        }
        
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let genId = this.props.navigation.state.params.chatFromId + 'connectedto' + this.props.navigation.state.params.chatToId;
        //AsyncStorage.setItem('chatgenid', genId);
        AsyncStorage.getItem('chatgenid', (err, chatgenidres) => {
            console.log(chatgenidres, 'from chat.js');
            this.setState({ chatgenidres: chatgenidres });
            this.get(message =>
                this.setState(previous => ({
                    messages: GiftedChat.append(previous.messages, message)

                }))
            );
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        
        this.off();
    }
    render() {
        const chat = <GiftedChat 
        messages={this.state.messages} 
        onSend={this.send} 
        user={this.user} 
        style={styles.messageContainer} 
        renderInputToolbar={props => customtInputToolbar(props)} 
        />;
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return (
               
                <View style={styles.container} behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={30} enabled>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', padding: 13, justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)' }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon name="arrow-left" size={20} onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.goBack() }} color="#FFF" />

                        
                    </View>
                    {chat}
                </View>
               
            )
        }
        return <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>{chat}</SafeAreaView>
    }
}
```

but when i run this application i get  " FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)." this error.what is wrong with my code.how to solve this.

Comment: can you try to create a minimal example that you expect would work? both for yourself, in debugging, and for answerers

Comment: this is the only code for chatting nothing else. only I used gifted chat. that's it.

Comment: Try with https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage, is much easier and tested

Comment: what is wrong with this code?